# How to specify Unix Makefile generator in CMake?

Tags: linux, cmake

I was compiling LLVM-7 so I can compile bcc, for there is a command to compile llvm-7 which is

```
cmake -G <generator> [options] <path to llvm sources>
```

I have no clue how to specify `<generator>`. Let us say I want to use `Unix Makefiles` as generator, what would be the above command and I want the llvm-7 to get installed in /usr/lib/llvm-7/ directory how to make this happen. Does any one know this?

When I tried like

```
  cmake -G Unix Makefile ./
```

It cause error

```
 Makefile ./
CMake Error: Could not create named generator Unix

Generators
* Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Green Hills MULTI            = Generates Green Hills MULTI files
                                 (experimental, work-in-progress).
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  Ninja Multi-Config           = Generates build-<Config>.ninja files.
  Watcom WMake                 = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
```

Answer (score 5):

Put the name of the generator in quotation marks like in

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
```

You can omit a space after the `-G` and use single quotation marks, too.

[Clang's documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) contains this in step 3:

```
cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm
```

This example shows how to add more options -- by passing flags after `-D`. To set the install prefix you have to set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` like in

```
cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<install_path> ../llvm
```